# Template Route Regex

Tags: template-routes, regex

What's the syntax for excluding phrases from segments in template routes?

For example, let's say I have a template group called "fruit."

I have a template A with the template route: "/fruit/{fruit:alpha-dash}" and that route matches:

- /fruit/apples
- /fruit/oranges
- /fruit/tomatoes

But I'd like to exclude just tomatoes from using template A so that it can match template B which is the next sequential template.

What would the regex look like to exclude tomatoes?

Answer (score 0):

There is a top-down order for how template routes are processed. So what you need to do is create your `tomato` route rule, and make sure it is **above** your regular `alpha_dash` rule. I couldn't find a simple solution for ignoring specific segments in a regex rule using the carat and didn't bother testing further; EE would yell at me for using some regex modifiers and such. The other way around was easier. Here's what worked for me in your example.

This is an example of a couple of rules in your `My site -> CP Home -> Design -> Template Manager -> Template Route Manager` that works for your exmample:

```
Group     Template          Route                            Segment Req
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
fruit     special_fruit     /fruit/{fruit:regex[(tomato)]}   Yes
fruit     regular_fruit     /fruit/{fruit:alpha_dash}        Yes
```

This will match `/fruit/tomato` to your `special_fruit` template. When that doesn't match (say `/fruit/apples`), it tries the next rule and will match and render your `regular_fruit` template.